# Sharding for slave node in master slave replication

Tags: mysql, sharding

Is it possible to configure `sharding` only for slave nodes in a master slave replication scheme?

Comment: Is this question specific to mysql database? I used sharding extensively in MongoDB and what I understand in general about sharding it is not possible to shard in salve node only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Sharding" is not supported directly in MySQL.  See other products, such as Spider.

If you meant "Partitioning", then elaborate on what you hope to gain and provide the partitioned and unpartitioned versions of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Okay, but my question was is it possible to do it for slave only in generally with Master-Slave replication scheme. Let's do not consider direct MySQL support in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused about what you want.  A Slave is _intended_ to be an exact copy of a Master (albeit slightly delayed).  A set of separate servers, each containing a "shard" of the data:  Each could be a Master with its own Slave(s).

Comment: So slave can not have separatley sharding if master doesn't have it right? Sharding will be possible if master has it and slave as well but not vise versa?

Comment: A single Master can be one server of a set of servers that "shard" the dataset.  Ditto for a Slave.  It takes many servers, _not_ connected by replication to comprise a "sharded dataset".  Again, perhaps you are referring to `PARTITION`?  See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)